# How can i controll two servo motor and buzzer with arduino mega2560 without using any library function

Tags: c, arduino, atmega

I have tried the following code...I have ran 1 servo successfully and 1 buzzer but I'm unable to run 2 servo at once....my code is not working as it should be... my servo pin was 11 & 12...and my buzzer pin is 5.....Here is my code and circuit diagram... the uno in my diagram is a mega just to be sure.... Again I can not use any library functions like pinMode() or any library for controlling buzzer or servo.... so here is my diagram and code

[this is the circuit diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyVp9.png)

```
#define servo90 3000                                    //OCR1A value for the servo to reach 90 degrees
#define servo0 1000                                     //OCR1A value for the servo to reach 0 degrees
#define servoA90 3000                                    //OCR1A value for the servo to reach 90 degrees
#define servoA0 1000


volatile unsigned long sysTick = 0;                                 //set up a global system tick variable
unsigned long oldSysTickServo = 0;

volatile unsigned long sysTickA = 0;                                 //set up a global system tick variable
unsigned long oldSysTickServoA = 0;

//Buzzer I/O signal is connected to PIN 5

int tune1[] = {261, 277, 294, 311, 330, 349, 370, 392, 415, 440};
int dur1[] = {500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 50};



int i, j, n = 10; //n is inialitsed to the number o fnotes in tune 1.
int tmp;
void setup() {
  DDRB = (1 << DDB5); //Set PB 5 (pin 11) to an output
  DDRB = (1 << DDB6);



  //set up a 1ms system tick timer
  cli();                                                //disable global interrupts
  TCCR0A = 0;
  TCCR0B = (1 << CS01) | (1 << CS00);                   //start the timer with a prescale of 64
  TIMSK0 = (1 << OCIE0A);                               //setup the output compare interrupt with OCR0A
  OCR0A = 250;                                          //set up the OCR0A value for exactly 1ms (or as close as the clock will allow)
  sei();                                                //enable global interrupts



  //setup the timer for fast PWM
  TCCR1A = (1 << COM1A1) | (1 << WGM11);                //Enable clear on OC1A
  TCCR1B = (1 << WGM13) | (1 << WGM12) | (1 << CS11);   //Set the prescale to 8 bits, Fast PWM with TOP in ICR1
  TCCR1C = 0;                                           //We dont need to do anything here, so make sure its shut off
  ICR1 = 40000;                                         //Set the top value to 40000. This should be a period of 20ms



  OCR1A = servo90;


  // setup the timer for 2nd pwm

  TCCR1A = (1 << COM1B1) | (1 << WGM11);                //Enable clear on OC1B
  TCCR1B = (1 << WGM13) | (1 << WGM12) | (1 << CS11);   //Set the prescale to 8 bits, Fast PWM with TOP in ICR1
  TCCR1C = 0;                                           //We dont need to do anything here, so make sure its shut off
  ICR1 = 40000;                                         //Set the top value to 40000. This should be a period of 20ms

  OCR1B = servoA90;


  // bazar timer count
  DDRE = (1 << DDE3);
  TCCR3A = (1 << COM3A1) | (1 << WGM31);
  TCCR3B = (1 << WGM33) | (1 << WGM32) | (1 << CS32);



}



void loop() {


  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ICR3 = tune1[i];
    OCR3A = tune1[i] / 2;
    TCNT3 = 0;


    for (j = 0; j < dur1[i]; j++) {
      _delay_ms(1);
    }



    ICR3 = 0; OCR3A = 0; TCNT3 = 0;



    //Has half a second passed?
    if (sysTickVal() >= oldSysTickServo + 500)
    {
      oldSysTickServo = sysTickVal();        //store the previous time
      //is the servo currently down?
      if (OCR1A == servo0)
      {
        //the servo is currently at 0 deg
        OCR1A = servo90;     //set the servo to 90deg
      }
      else
      {
        //the servo is currently at 90 deg
        OCR1A = servo0;     //set the servo to 90deg
      }
    }
    //Has half a second passed?
    if (sysTickValA() >= oldSysTickServoA + 500)
    {
      oldSysTickServoA = sysTickValA();        //store the previous time
      //is the servo currently down?
      if (OCR1B == servoA0)
      {
        //the servo is currently at 0 deg
        OCR1B = servoA90;     //set the servo to 90deg
      }
      else
      {
        //the servo is currently at 90 deg
        OCR1B = servoA0;     //set the servo to 90deg
      }
    }
  }




}
ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect)
{
  sysTickA++;
  sysTick++;
  //increment the system tick time every 1ms
  TCNT0 = 0;        //reset the timer
}





/**************************************************************************************************************************************/
//Function Name: get sysTick
//Inputs:
//Outputs:
//Hardware:
//Description: return the sytick value without any collitions
unsigned long sysTickValA()
{
  unsigned long val;    //create a variable to store the sysTick value
  cli();                //disable gloabl interrupt
  val = sysTickA;        //read in the current system time
  sei();                //enable global interrupt
  return val;           //return the current system time
}
unsigned long sysTickVal()
{
  unsigned long val;    //create a variable to store the sysTick value
  cli();                //disable gloabl interrupt
  val = sysTick;        //read in the current system time
  sei();                //enable global interrupt
  return val;           //return the current system time
}
```

Comment: Not sure it’s the entire problem but you should bitwise-or | (or add) the two bits into DDRB - the way you’re doing it only DDB6 is set to 1

Comment: I tried your solution but still only pin 12 is working...pin 11 is not working

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two assignments to DDRB which only leaves the last one active, use a single assignment with both bits set, like:

```
DDRB = (1<<DDB5) | (1<<DDB6)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still only pin 12 is working...pin 11 is not working